# Typescript compiler can't find node with yarn - Cannot find type definition file for 'node'

Tags: typescript, webpack, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

I have @types/node installed. I'm using Yarn 2 (PnP). Seems like Typescript can't find the @types/node package?

Running `yarn build` with the build script being `webpack` shows errors about cannot resolving modules (path, buffer etc)

Running `tsc` shows `TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.`

**Running 'ts-node'** however does work properly.

My tsconfig.json is below:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": [
      "ES2020",
      "DOM"
    ],
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

My webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  entry: "./src/server.ts",
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {
            transpileOnly: true,
            experimentalWatchApi: true,
            onlyCompileBundledFiles: true,
          },
        }],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem is that tsc (Typescript v4.3.5) currently doesn't support PnP, and will need the [@yarnpkg/pnpify tool](https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/pnpify) as a workaround.

Comment: From [PnPify](https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/pnpify) link: *"PnPify is mostly deprecated since Yarn supports [`node_modules`](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#nodeLinker) installs out of the box."*

Comment: @icc97 I think you are confusing installing packages via Yarn with tsc, the typescript compiler. The compiler doesn't support PnP, it expects node_modules folder. Yarn can install packages like npm to node_modules, or in yarn/cache as PnP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this message inside VSCode it could be because you need to integrate [Yarn PnP with VSCode](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks#vscode):

> 1. Install the [ZipFS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=arcanis.vscode-zipfs) extension, which is maintained by the Yarn team.
> 2. Run the following command, which will generate a `.vscode/settings.json` file:
>
>    ```bash
>    yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode
>    ```
> 3. For safety reason VSCode requires you to explicitly activate the custom TS settings:
>
>    1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> in a TypeScript file
>    2. Choose "Select TypeScript Version"
>    3. Pick "Use Workspace Version"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on my computer by re-installing node.js, as the program yarn is relying on. Simply download node.js and run the installer - it was nothing to do with yarn packages, though I tried all sorts of yarn commands, even clearing the cache, as a puzzle as the project had previously compiled and run.